# iterate apps script function over all rows

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach

I've got this working script:

```
function computeRows(){
  
  for(var row=lastRow;row>1;row--){
    if(ss.getRange('Q'+row).isBlank()){
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('184C3kCDDv2sCElQB-INIyzTvmx8oNDXF0xqO7AH7xs8');
      var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
      var currentRow = ss.getActiveSelection().getRow();
      var phone = 'E'+lastRow;
      
      ss.getRange('S'+lastRow).setValue('request');
      ss.getRange('W'+lastRow).setFormula('A'+lastRow); // ('Now()');
      ss.getRange('X'+lastRow).setFormula('CONCATENATE(C'+lastRow+'&" "&D'+lastRow+')');
      ss.getRange('Y'+lastRow).setFormula('CONCATENATE(F'+lastRow+'&"\n"&G'+lastRow+'&" "&H'+lastRow+')')
      ss.getRange('Z'+lastRow).setFormula('CONCATENATE("("&LEFT('+phone+',3)&") "&MID('+phone+',4,3)&"-"&RIGHT('+phone+',4))');  
      ss.getRange('AA'+lastRow).setFormula('B'+lastRow);
      
      var UNIQUEID = ss.getRange('Q'+lastRow);
      UNIQUEID.setValue('=DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8)');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      UNIQUEID.copyTo(UNIQUEID,{contentsOnly:true});
    
    }
  }
}
```

I need it to iterate over all the rows in my table not just on the last row. I've tried various combinations of `lastrow` and `row` but just confuse myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Debugged script to try

```js
function computeRows(){
  
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow(); // Moved this outside of for loop
  
  for(var row=lastRow;row>1;row--){
    if(ss.getRange('Q'+row).isBlank()){
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('184C3kCDDv2sCElQB-INIyzTvmx8oNDXF0xqO7AH7xs8');
      
      // var currentRow = ss.getActiveSelection().getRow(); // This is not referenced again
      
      var phone = 'E'+row;
      
      ss.getRange('S'+row).setValue('request');
      ss.getRange('W'+row).setFormula('A'+row); // ('Now()');
      ss.getRange('X'+row).setFormula('CONCATENATE(C'+row+'&" "&D'+row+')');
      ss.getRange('Y'+row).setFormula('CONCATENATE(F'+row+'&"\n"&G'+row+'&" "&H'+row+')')
      ss.getRange('Z'+row).setFormula('CONCATENATE("("&LEFT('+phone+',3)&") "&MID('+phone+',4,3)&"-"&RIGHT('+phone+',4))');  
      ss.getRange('AA'+row).setFormula('B'+row);
      
      var UNIQUEID = ss.getRange('Q'+row);
      UNIQUEID.setValue('=DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8)');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      UNIQUEID.copyTo(UNIQUEID,{contentsOnly:true});
    
    }
  }
}
```

- Inside the for loop I replaced all instances of `lastRow` with `row`. In your for loop, the value that changes each iteration is`row` with `var row=lastRow` setting it to the number of the last row. Then within your loop, for example with:

```
ss.getRange('S'+lastRow)
```

Will call the same last row every single time. So you need to change this to:

```
ss.getRange('S'+row)
```

- I moved the initialization of `lastRow` outside the for loop. If you want to set a maximum for the loop, you only need to set it once.

#### Reference

- [MDN for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) - I suggest maybe experimenting with a few example for loops to get a feel for how they work. I apologize if you already know this, but by the code it doesn't seem that you understand.